# Problems recovering BCH accidentally sent to BTC address

Tags: bitcoin-cash, cross-chain-recovery

I am one of those people who transferred BCH from bitcoinpurser.com into my electrum wallet that only takes BTC. I have read several articles and have installed and created an elctroncash wallet. I can see that the two have successfully synchronized but on both the transaction still shows as pending. I originally transferred the BCH on September 5. I created the electron cash wallet on the 19th. I would think that it should have come through by now.  Shouldn't it? How long does it usually take?  So, I am wondering if I sent it to the correct address. Is there a way for me to check that? I have a crypto address from bitcoinpurser when I sent them.

Comment: What the address you sent the coins to? Does it start with a 1 or a 3?

Comment: The crypto address I sent from starts with qqc. The receiving address from my electrum wallet I sent it to starts with a 1.

Comment: OK, if its a 1 then you're safe. copy the address you sent it tp and paste it here https://explorer.bitcoin.com. you should see the balance.

Comment: Should I create a wallet with this site?  Do I request the full amount or the amount minus the fees?

Comment: I entered the receiving address but it shows a 0 balance. It is possible I sent it to a different address. I am new to all of this. I know I generated an address from electrum but I am not sure I saved it correctly. I found the transaction on BTC.com by entering the crypto address I sent it from and it shows up there but I don't understand how to read the page to find out the address I sent it to.

Comment: I looked up the crypto address it was sent from on the link you gave me and it shows up there too. Again I don't know how to read the page but it says there are 4 inputs and 2 outputs on the 5th of September. 1 of the outputs is for fees the other is  the balance less the fees but I cant tell where they were output to.

Comment: Can you provide a transaction id, so we can be able to help you out

Comment: Where do I find a transaction id? Is it ok for me to post the receiving address here?

Comment: You can post the receiving address so we could check, there's no way we can help without it.

Comment: Receiving address I have is 19EsSXxaTParaHqQ7V8o9A9xbZ47fApe7f